# tmux: How to automatically list-sessions when starting a new tmux sessions?

Tags: tmux

Sometime I do have a couple of sessions already running, I didn't name them or I use random name.

Currently I have to `ctrl-a` and `s` or `:list-sessions` in order to list all sessions and switch to them.

When I started a new tmux via `tmux` command. How can I automatically list existing sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a shell function (for Bash) for this. When I run `tmux` without any options and there are already some sessions it'll prompt for me to choose one.

```bash
function _tmux()
{
    if [[ $# == 0 ]] && command tmux ls >& /dev/null; then
        command tmux attach \; choose-tree -s
    else
        command tmux "$@"
    fi
}

alias tmux=_tmux
```

Comment: I was hoping it is possible to stick it in the `.tmux.conf` :D. 
